# Whats the benefit of initializing your variables late in the function than at the start of a function body?

Tags: c++, variables

Ive been reading a excellent book written by Bjarne Stroustrup and he recommends that you declare variables as late as possible, preferable just before you use it, however it fails to mention any benefits over declaring the variables late than at the start of the function body.

So what is the benefit of declaring variable late like this:

```
int main()
{
  /* some
     code
     here
  */
  int MyVariable1;
  int MyVariable2;
  std::cin >> MyVariable1 >> MyVariable2;
  return(0);
}
```

instead of at the start of a function body like this:

```
int main()
{
  int MyVariable1;
  int MyVariable2;
  /* some 
     code
     here
  */
  std::cin >> MyVariable1 >> MyVariable2;
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i will be accepting an answer in several minutes once the timer runs out. I was just curious if it had anything to do with compilation or any thing like that. But its just turned out to be for human readability.

Comment: it's not all about human readability. see my points about default-construction and exceptions

Comment: @Harrythehacker: You seem to have ignored a good 80% of the content of the answers. Please read them more thoroughly and don't rush to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, that you deal with some objects and construction of these objects is an expensive operation. In such situation there are a few reasons why it is better to define variables just before their usage:

1) First of all, it is sometimes faster to create an object using appropriate constructor instead of default-constructing and assignment. So this:

```
T obj(/* some arguments here */);
```

may be faster then this:

```
T obj;
/* some code here*/
obj = T(/* some arguments here */);
```

Note that in the first example only a single constructor is invoked. But in the second example default constructor and assignment operator are invoked.

2) If an exception is thrown somewhere between object definition and its first usage you just do unnecessary work creating and destroying your object without any usage at all. The same is applicable when function returns between object definition and its first usage.

3) Yes, readability is also worth to mention here :)

Comment: _"it is usually faster to create object and initialise it in the same time"_ You cannot initialise an object at any other time than when you create it. Your second example is an example of after-the-fact assignment. The performance angle is not strictly incorrect but you'd have to have a _very_ peculiar default constructor for the difference to actually be in any way noticeable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Great remark! Thank you. I will adjust my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Harrythehacker I believe that David's answer is much more complete. In my opinion it is better to mark his answer as accepted)

Answer (score 5):

It makes the code easier to follow. In general, you declare variables when you need them, e.g. near a loop when you want to find a minimum of something via that loop. In this way, when someone reads your code, (s)he doesn't have to try to decipher what 25 variables mean at the start of a function, but the variables will "explain" themselves when going through the code. After all, it's not important to know what variables mean, but to understand what the code does.

Remember that most of the time you use that local variable in a very small portion of your code, so it makes sense to define it in that small portion where you need it.

Answer (score 5):

A few points that comes to mind

1. Not all objects are default - constructible , so many times declaring the object in the beginning of the function is not an option, only on assignment (aka `auto myObj = creationalfunction();`)
2. your function gets smaller number of lines, hence more readable. declaring each variable in the beginning of the function really makes it a few lines bigger, throughout the code.
3. if your function throws - it's not economical to build a list of objects, just to destroy them on stack-unwinding
4. declaring variables in the same line they are assigned can let you use `auto`, which makes the code times more flexible.
5. it's the common convention for C++ these days, and that is pretty important.
6. create an object + assign it later on might be more slow than directly initialize an object with values.

Comment: Nice reasons! Seems that you've mention everything I decided to write in my own answer :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

If "other code" is a page of code then you can't actually see the declaration on the screen when you read the values. If you thought that you were reading two doubles, you can't see on the screen that you are wrong. If you declare the variable on one line and use it on the next, any mistake would be obvious.

Comment: Mind you, if your function is this long, then you've already failed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's your opinion, and one that I find highly debatable.

Comment: @gnasher729: From from just "my opinion", it's a generally accepted consensus that large functions are to be avoided. Of course you are free to disagree with that consensus.

Answer (score 1):

When starting to get good at programming you will usually end up holding the entire program in your head at the same time.  Later, you will learn how to reduce this to one function in your head.

Both of these limit how large/complex a program or function you can work with.  You can help this problem by simplifying what is going on so you no longer have to think about it: reduce your working memory needs.  Also you can trade one kind of complexity for another; fsncy variable value dancing for some complex higher level algorithm, or for certainty of code correctness.

There are many ways to do this.  You can work with chunkable patterns, and think in those patterns instead of in lower level primitives (this is basically what you did when you graduated from whole program state to single function state).  You can also do this by making your state simpler.

Every variable carries state.  It modifies what that line of code means, and what every previous line of code means up to the point of its declaration.  A variable that exists on a line could be modified by the line or read by the line.  To understand what the reading of a variable means, you have to audit every line between its declaration and its use for the possibility it is edited.

Now, this may not happen: but **checking it** both takes time and working memory.  If you have 10 variables, having to remember which of them where modified "above" and which not and what their values mean can burn a lot of headspace.

On the other hand, a variable created, used, and either falling out of scope or never used again is not going to cause this cognitive load.  You do not have to check for hidden state or meaning.  What more, you are not tempted -- indeed not able -- to use it prior to that line.  You are definitely not going to overwrite important state that later code relies on when you set it, and you are not going to have it modified to something surprising between initialization and use.

In short, reduce the "state space" of the lines of code you use it, and even don't use it in.

Sometimes this is difficult to achieve, and sometimes impractical or impossible.  But quite often it is easy, improves code quality, makes it easier to read or understand.  The most important audience of code is humans, there is a reason we don't check in the object file output of a compiler (or some intermediate representation).

Suc "low state" code is also way easier to modify after the fact.  In the limit, it becomes pure functional code.